# Unable to plot values on scatterplot using vba

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I am relatively new to VBA. I am attempting to automate the generation of a graph containing Beta values using the following steps:

Step 1 - Generate a list of random numbers in Column A
Step 2 - Based on values in Column A, apply the Beta.Dist formula in Column B
Step 3 - Generate a scatterplot based on values in Column B, the scatterplot should look like a U-shaped distribution curve

I've tried using the following code but I am only seeing 1 value in the scatter plot (i.e., the scatterplot only has one dot).

Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub Macro1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i%, j%
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection = "0.99"
    Selection.Offset(0, 1) = "Beta(" & Selection & ", " & Selection & ") Density"
    For i = 1 To 301
        Selection.Offset(i, 0).Formula = "= rand()"
        Selection.Offset(i, 1).Formula = "=BETA.DIST(A2:A302,0.99,0.99,False)"
    Next i
    j = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, xlXYScatter, 98 + j * 10, 16.5 + j * 10, 319, 296.5).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B302")
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(j + 1).Activate
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    Selection.Caption = "="
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 1
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorGridlines.Delete
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1.1
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.000#"
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
    Range("E1") = ""
    Range("I1") = ""
    Range("B1").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'm hoping to get a U-shaped beta distribution curve in the scatter plot. Appreciate any form of help and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the chart data correctly:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B302")
```